# Why is this Django QuerySet returning no results?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have this Class in a project, and I'm trying to get previous and next elements of current one.

```
def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(GuidePage, self).get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
    context = get_article_context(context)

    all_guides = GuidePage.objects.all().order_by("-date")

    context['all_guides'] = all_guides

    context['next_guide'] = all_guides.filter(date__lt=self.date)

    context['prev_guide'] = all_guides.filter(date__gt=self.date)

    print context['next_guide']
    print context['prev_guide']

    return context
```

These two lines:

```
context['prev_guide'] = all_guides.filter(date__lt=self.date)
context['next_guide'] = all_guides.filter(date__gt=self.date)
```

are returning empty results as printed in the console:

```
(QuerySet[])
(QuerySet[])
```

What am I missing?

***EDIT:***

I changed *lt* and *gt* to ***lte*** and ***gte***. As I understand that will include results that are also equal in date.

In this case I got ALL elements. All elements were created the same day, but, of course, at different times, so they should be different by minutes. Is this difference not taking into account when filtering for ***greater/lesser*** ?

Comment: Where `self.date` is declared?

Comment: I thought it is refering to the current element date? Maybe I'm wrong there, I'm a newbie at Python/Django

Comment: Show the whole `class` definition please. Also, what *current element date* you mean? Do you mean the current date, say 30 Mar 2017?

Comment: I mean the date field value of the current element. That's the date the element was created. 
When I print the date it is actually returning the correct value. I don't think the date field is the problem

Comment: So, when you `print(self.date)` you actually get a date, right?

Comment: That's correct, I get a date (not today's date). I will add an edit to the main question, please read it because it may give a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter not only by date, but time also, you must change the relevant field in your model to be of `DateTimeField` instead of `DateField`.

Like this:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Now, you can do stuff like `all_guides.filter(date_time__lte=self.date_time)` or `all_guides.filter(date_time__gte=self.date_time)`.

Carefull of the two underscores `__`.